# addClass removeClass bugs jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery code that simply switches classes on click, so i have two elements one with a class video-left the other video middle, and on click they switch classes, this is working in fire bug the classes switch and also their positions (which are related to classes), but when i click a second time the jQuery acts as if the classes did not change ... 
followig is the code:

```
$('.video-left').click(function(){
   $('.video-middle').addClass('video-left');
   $('.video-middle').removeClass('video-middle');
   $(this).addClass('video-middle');
   $(this).removeClass('video-left');
});
$('.video-middle').click(function(){alert('middle');});
```

so if i click left first then what is now left it triggers the alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do something like `$( '.video-left' ).click()` the click event is attached to the *element*, not to the *class*. That is, if the element's class changes, the click event doesn't change because the event is attached to the element itself.

In this case when you want to attach the event to a *class* you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that has the selector checked individually every time the user clicks on the element.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.video-left', function(e) {
   // ...
});
```

(You could also use any parent of the video elements instead of `document`, provided that they don't change at any point.)

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong

What you do is attaching events to elements, you don't attach elements to classes, as you suppose

And each time when you click on the element, that was .video-left the function that resides in first click() executed. Same one

What you should do, is to add class "video" to all elements and to attach common event

```
$('.video').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('.video-left')) {do_something1();return} 
if($(this).hasClass('.video-middle')) {do_something2();return}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class video-left to both the elements and add the class 'video-middle' (along with 'video-left' to the element you want 'video-middle' to be by default.

```
<div class='video-left'></div>
<div class='video-left video-middle'></div> <!--default video middle -->
```

Then

```
$('.video-left').click(function(){
    $('.video-middle').removeClass('video-middle');
    $(this).addClass('video-middle');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the 'click' event you don't have a persistent selector, so when you remove the `video-left` class without rebinding it will no longer handle the event.

```
$('.video-left').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.video-middle').addClass('video-left').removeClass('video-middle')
  $(this).addClass('video-middle').removeClass('video-left')
})


$('.video-middle').on('click', function(){ alert('middle'); })
```